# Switches/Batch File command seem to have changed

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, updates, patch

A couple of years back, I had to update about 300 offsite Windows 7, 32-bit computers with a number of updates/patches via batch script.  I have to do the same again, yet the commands that worked two years ago don't seem to be working today.

I tried running my batch script, but it seemed to stop at the point where I run the updates.  Decided to test it directly at the command line.

In testing the three largest files (all three are Microsoft updates with a .msu extension), I put them in the /Temp folder, then use the command

```
FOR %%b IN (*.msu) DO wusa.exe %%b /quiet /norestart
```

Worked two years ago.  Now I get

```
%%b was unexpected at this time.
```

So I changed the command to

```
FOR %b IN (*.msu) DO wusa.exe %b /quiet /norestart
```

That immediately put all three patches almost simultaneously into the command line.  So I'm assuming my FOR loop just needs the single %?  Waited about ten minutes, then rebooted my system.  None of the patches had applied.

Picked one of the patches, tried

```
wusa.exe patch.msu /quiet /norestart
```

with just one of the patches.  Waited ten minutes and rebooted.  Did not apply.  Finally, ran wusa.exe patch.msu and walked through the interface to install it - took only about one minute.  Rebooted the system and that patch had applied.

So why aren't the /quiet and /norestart switches working to install these patches?

Comment: When executing a `for` loop in the command prompt (`cmd`), use a single `%` sign for its variable references; when using a `for` loop in a batch file, use two `%` signs; type `for /?` into a command prompt window and read the help very carefully...

Comment: Thank you for the info on the %% command line versus batch file.

I tried the /? and it tells me it should be /quiet /norestart that I should be using, yet they don't seem to install the files.

Comment: Aha!  Finally found that it did install ONE patch and once that patch was installed, the other two no longer applied to the PC.